# OpenOffice::OODoc - How to insert Horizontal Line/Rule in a Page

Tags: perl, odf

I am creating ODF Document using [OpenOffice::OODoc](https://metacpan.org/pod/OpenOffice::OODoc) module. I want to have a Horizontal Line/Rule after a Heading.

I have seen documentation but it has no solution for this problem. I even tried to insert a paragraph with border, but it leaves a vertical white space after top border and next line.

Any idea how can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

> I've noticed that there are two methods--which I'm aware of--to
>   accomplish this task. There's Insert > Horizontal Ruler or by applying
>   a bottom border to the a paragraph.
>
> From what it appears, the "Horizontal Ruler" is just an image inserted
>   in the text. - [OpenOffice forum](https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=11147)

So I think you could use an image (which contains a line).

```
$document->createImageStyle
                (
                "NewImageStyle",
                properties      =>
                        {
                        'draw:luminance'        => '20%',
                        'draw:color-inversion'  => 'true'
                        }
                );

$document->createImageElement
                (
                "Image1",
                style           => "NewImageStyle",
                attachment      => $newparagraph,
                import          => "path\to\rule.jpg"
                );
```